# How to process XML sent via POST?

Tags: php, xml, http, post

I'm receiving XML sent via POST. Naturally I need to parse this XML to get at the goodies it holds for me. However, when I receive the XML is seems that PHP is parsing it like a query string.

For example, this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ForgotPassword>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <authentication>
        <login>myresllerid</login>
        <apikey>1234567890abcdef</apikey>
    </authentication>
    <parameters>
        <emailAddress>joesmith@example.com</emailAddress>
    </parameters>
</ForgotPassword>
```

Becomes this (from `print_r($_REQUEST)`):

```
Array
(
    [
<?xml_version] => "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<IDCForgotPassword>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <authentication>
        <login>myresllerid</login>
        <apikey>1234567890abcdef</apikey>
    </authentication>
    <parameters>
        <emailAddress>joesmith@example.com</emailAddress>
    </parameters>
</IDCForgotPassword>
)
```

You can see the XML is being broken up at the first equals sign (=) in the XML into a key/value pair.

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Can we see your POST form please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless enctype is *multipart/form-data* use [php://input](http://php.net/wrappers.php) to fetch the raw input.

```
$c = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: What do you do if it is [*multipart/form-data* (RFC 2388)](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2388) in PHP?

Comment: hakra: That would be handled by the mechanism described under http://docs.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php